# Work done on the gas when a mass M is kept on the piston

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider a perfectly insulating cylinder enclosing a gas at pressure same as external atmospheric pressure $P_o$. Now a mass $M$ is placed on the piston. What will be the work done on the gas when the gas comes again in equilibrium.
Now according to my sources if the piston is displaced by distance $h$ the work done on gas is $Mgh$. 
But I think it should be different than this. As the process is irreversible the internal pressure will not vary uniformly. We have to calculate the work by using external pressure on the piston. So the work done on gas should be $$\int(P_o + \frac{Mg}{A}) dV $$ 
This expression takes into account work done by force due to mass and also due to atmosphere but Mgh doesn't consider the work done by atmosphere. So where am I wrong here?

Comment: What work does the atmosphere do on the gas without the weight?

Comment: The key quesiton is *what is the system on which work is done ?*.  Gas, o gas+mass ?

Comment: @GiorgioP the actual question is to find final temp given initial temp. So we would require to find work done on gas. Not gas+mass

Comment: @Bob D $\int P_{o} dV$ but if mass is not placed it will remain in equilibrium.

Comment: In my judgment, you are absolutely correct.  The work done by the surroundings *on the gas* is exactly as you have written it (assuming a massless piston), except for the sign. It should be $-(P_0+\frac{Mg}{A})(V_f-V_i)$

Comment: @ChetMiller This is probably a dumb question, and I'm almost embarrassed to ask it, but how does the atmosphere compress the gas when the gas pressure is never less than that of the atmosphere? If the total work done is $-P_{0}(V_{f}-V_{i})-\frac{Mg}{A}(V_{f}-V_{i})$ what is the value of the first term?

Comment: @BobD I'm not sure I understand the question, but the total absolute downward force exerted on the top of the massless piston is $P_0A+Mg$.  And this force is applied through a displacement $(V_i-V_f)/A$.  The value of the first term is the part of the work due to the external atmospheric pressure.  The fact that $P_o$ doesn't exceed the gas pressure is irrelevant because it only represents part of force exerted on the gas.

Comment: @Chet Miller are you sure it's right. Cause my source is quite trustable.

Comment: @Chet Miller I thought a bit more on this. What I think is as the mass will also accelerate, suppose N is the normal reaction between piston and block then work done on gas is $\int -(P_o -\frac{N}{A}) dV$ and there will also be some kinetic energy $\int (Mg-N) dh= \frac{1}{2}Mv^2$ so actually how does the kinetic energy dissipate will give the actual work done on gas in equilibrium

Comment: @ATHARVA Chet is a thermodynamics guru, which is why I hesitated to ask the question. I trust him. Just trying to learn from him.

Comment: @ChetMiller I understand what you're saying. I guess I'm looking at this through a lens that tells  me the work done on something is the net force acting on it times the displacement. In that respect, the net force is mg downward.

Comment: @Bob D The work done on a gas is not the net force times the displacement.  It is the integral of the force times displacement *over each part of the boundary where displacement occurs.*. The displacement of the closed end of the cylinder is zero, so there is no work done on the gas there.  All the work is done at the piston face.

Comment: @ChetMiller Having trouble visualizing "displacement over each part of the boundary where displacement occurs". But now I'm thinking differently to help understand why atmospheric pressure counts. The gas is initially in equilibrium with the atmosphere. The weight mg is applied. The gas compresses irreversibly and eventually the gas is in thermal and mechanical equilibrium. Its final pressure is $\frac{mg}{A} + P_{0}$. I remove the weight. The gas now expands against constant external pressure $P_0$ returning to its original state.

Comment: @ChetMiller Ergo since the gas had to do work against atmospheric pressure in the expansion the atmosphere had to do work on the gas during the compression. Am I thinking about that right?

Comment: @Bob D That's certainly one way of looking at it.

Comment: @ATHARVA has any of this helped you?